# Image binding with Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picasso

Coming from Android I'm used to using picasso to handle image binding to my adapter, so my question is in xamarin.forms what class or package can I use to implement similar feature.
 What I want to basically achieve is this. 
I'm binding a list template which has an image element to a collection of objects(Food items). Each object has a url link to an image. So when populating the view, the image element should be able to read the url and update the image with the image gotten. Picasso handles this normally with Android using Android studio.

Comment: I'm not familiar with picasso, but a bit with Xamarin.Forms. If you could explain more about what you're trying to do, then there are more people who could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article should contain what you want to do: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

I guess you want to achieve something like this: **FromUri** - Requires a Uri object, eg. `new Uri("http://server.com/image.jpg")`

Comment: Yeah. This could work . Is there a way to set placeholder image? Like before the image loads.

Comment: I do not know that. Maybe this piece of text has the info what you need: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images . This could also be a better solution then FromUri, depending on what you want to do excactly.

Comment: Most of the time I Google: Xamarin iOS [subject], most of the time i get a solution to my problem.